# Dynamically replace the string in editor

Tags: regex, excel, dynamic, replace, notepad++

I'm looking for one solution:
I wanted to replace particular text into other formatted string

Ex.

> select * from tab where col like '%`ab-de`%' => select * from tab
>   where regexp(col,'`ab-de`( |$|\.\:)')
>
> select * from tab where col like '%`9-01`%' => select * from tab
>   where regexp(col, '`9-01`( |$|\.\:)'

so here, basically I'd like to replace the string (`ab-de or 9-01`) whatever in between %`x`%

=>  need to place exact the same string inside regexp 2nd argument. (`regexp(col, 'x( |$|\.\: )'`

I know there must be some way to get this done- but not able to figure out how.

Either using regex or some macro in notepad++ or Excel or some other editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\w+)\s+like\s+'%(.+?)%'`
- Replace with: `REGEXP\($1,'$2\( |$|\\.\\:\)'\)`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Note: parenthesis have to be escaped in replacement part

I guess you want `( |$|\.|\:)` in replacement part, so:

- Replace with: `REGEXP\($1,'$2\([\\ .\\:]|$\)'\)`

  does the job

**Explanation:**

```
(           : Start capture group 1
    \w+     : 1 or more alphanum or _ (ie. word character)
)           : end group
\s+         : 1 or more spaces
like        : literally the word like
\s+         : 1 or more spaces
'           : literally a single quote
%           : literally a percent sign
(           : Start capture group 2
    .+?     : 1 or more any character
)           : end group
%           : literally a percent sign
'           : literally a single quote
```

Replacement part:

```
REGEXP      : literally
\(          : opening parenthesis
  $1        : content of group 1, here the name of the column
  ,         : a comma
  '$2'      : content of group 2, here what is between % and %
  ,         : a comma
  \(        : opening parenthesis
    [ .:]|$ : literally [ .:]|$,  that represent in the resulting regex a space or a dot or a colon or  end of line
  \)        : closing parenthesis
\)          : closing parenthesis
```

Comment: Nice, @Toto! Would you please explain in a brief- how does it work?